# Función de evaluación de un juego de gato (tic-tac-toe): ¿Cuál es el error?

Tags: python, funciones, revisión-de-código

En un curso que tomo sobre Python tenemos como tarea hacer un juego de gato, aunque en cierto punto decidí hacer mi propia función para evaluar. Iré paso por paso en el código para explicarme.

```
#Primero cargamos las librerías
import numpy as np
import random

#Insertamos un tablero vacío
def create_board():
    board= np.zeros((3,3))
    return board

board= create_board()

#Creamos una función para ingresar valores (1 para el primer jugador y 2 para el segundo 

def random_place(board,player):
    placement= possibilities(board)
    if len(placement)>0:
        placement = random.choice(placement)
        place(board, player, placement)
    return board

#Función para crear juegos completos de gato 
def play_game():
    board= create_board()
    for i in range(5):
        random_place(board,1) 
        random_place(board,2)
    print(board)

play_game()


#Creamos una función para evaluar quién gana por filas

def row_win(board,player):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        if np.all(board[i]==player):   
            return True
        else:
            return False

#Luego otra para evaluar quién gana por columnas

def col_win(board,player):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        if np.all(board[:,i]==1):   
            return True
        else:
            return False

#Finalmente, una para evaluar quién gana en diagonales

def diag_win(board, player):
    if np.all(np.diag(board)==player) or    np.all(np.diag(np.fliplr(board))==player):
        return True
    else:
        return False

#La función de evaluación que hasta ahora he construido

def evaluate(x):       
    if row_win(board,1) or col_win(board,1) or diag_win(board,1):
        return "Gana jugador 1"
    elif row_win(board,2) or col_win(board,2) or diag_win(board,2):
        return "Gana jugador 2"
    else:
        return "Nadie gana"
```

Con todo lo anterior, llegamos al punto crítico de mi duda. Al correr de forma repetida:

```
gato= play_game()
evaluate(gato)
```

Obtengo siempre "Nadie gana" aunque tenga filas o columnas con 1 o 2.

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal en mi función de evaluación? ¿Está el error en algún paso previo?

---

**Edición**

Intento hacer ahora una función que me permita crear un juego completo de gato en cada llamada. Teniendo la función básica para crear un tablero vacío:

```
def create_board():
    board= np.zeros((3,3))
    return board
```

Invoco esta pero me regresa también un tablero vacío. ¿Podrías orientarme con el código?

```
def juego(board, player):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for player in [1,2]:
            placement= random.choice(player)
            if np.any(board==0):
                np.insert(board, placement, placement)
        print(board)

juego(board, (1,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que **solo compruebas la primera fila o columna**, tienes:

```
for i in range(len(board)):
   if np.all(board[:,i]==1):   
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

Este código solo itera una vez, siempre retorna en la primera iteración y lógicamente una función termina cuando retorna. No necesitas el `for` para nada, para ver si toda la fila tiene un mismo valor basta con hacer:

```
np.all(board == player, axis = 1)
```

Esto nos retorna un array booleano en el que cada elemento indica si esa fila tiene todos sus elementos igual a 1:

```
>>> board= np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                     [2, 2, 1],
                     [1, 1, 1]])
>>> np.all(board == 1, axis = 1)

array([True, False, True], dtype=bool)
```

Solo necesitamos aplicar `np.any` sobre el array para que retorne `True` si alguna cumple la condición:

```
import numpy as np


#Creamos una función para evaluar quién gana por filas

def row_win(board,player):
    return np.any(np.all(board == player, axis = 1))


#Luego otra para evaluar quién gana por columnas

def col_win(board,player):
    return np.any(np.all(board == player, axis = 0))


#Finalmente, una para evaluar quién gana en diagonales

def diag_win(board, player):
    return np.all(np.diag(board)==player) or np.all(np.diag(np.fliplr(board))==player)


#La función de evaluación que hasta ahora he construido

def evaluate(board):       
    if row_win(board,1) or col_win(board,1) or diag_win(board,1):
        return "Gana jugador 1"
    elif row_win(board,2) or col_win(board,2) or diag_win(board,2):
        return "Gana jugador 2"
    else:
        return "Nadie gana"
```

**Tests:**

```
#Nadie gana
board= np.array([[1, 1, 2],
                 [2, 2, 1],
                 [1, 1, 2]])  
print(evaluate(board))

#Gana 1 (fila 1)
board= np.array([[1, 2, 2],
                 [2, 2, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1]])
print(evaluate(board))

#Gana 2 (columna 3)
board= np.array([[1, 1, 2],
                 [2, 1, 2],
                 [1, 2, 2]])    
print(evaluate(board))

#Gana 2 (diagonal secundaria)
board= np.array([[1, 1, 2],
                 [2, 2, 1],
                 [2, 1, 2]])    
print(evaluate(board))

#Gana 1 (diagonal)
board= np.array([[1, 2, 2],
                 [2, 1, 1],
                 [1, 2, 1]])    
print(evaluate(board))
```

**Salida:**

> Nadie gana
>   Gana jugador 1
>   Gana jugador 2
>   Gana jugador 2
>   Gana jugador 1

---

**Edición**

---

Para simular un juego entre dos jugadores (sin inteligencia artificial, solo colocando las fichas de forma aleatoria) puedes hacer algo como:

```
import itertools
import numpy

def juego(board, players):
    # Se elige el orden de los jugadores:
    np.random.shuffle(players)
    players = itertools.cycle(players)

    #Se procede a llenar el tablero por turnos:
    indices = list(range(9))
    for i in range(9):
        placement= np.random.choice(indices)
        indices.remove(placement)
        player = next(players)
        board[np.unravel_index(placement, (3, 3))] = player

        print(board, "\n")
```

La función primero escoge de forma aleatoria el orden de los jugadores. Hecho esto, cada uno de ellos va colocando su ficha **por turnos** en los espacios disponibles. Se elige una posición aleatoria del array en una dimensión y luego se extrapola ese indice al array 2d con `np.unravel_index`.

Dado que un jugador gana cuando consigue los tres en linea, podemos integrar esto con el resto del código de forma que el juego termine cuando un jugador gana:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np


def row_win(board,player):
    return np.any(np.all(board == player, axis = 1))

def col_win(board,player):
    return np.any(np.all(board == player, axis = 0))

def diag_win(board, player):
    return np.all(np.diag(board)==player) or np.all(np.diag(np.fliplr(board))==player)


def create_board():
    board= np.zeros((3,3))
    return board

def juego(board, players):
    # Se elige el orden de los jugadores:
    np.random.shuffle(players)
    players = itertools.cycle(players)

    #Se procede a llenar el tablero por turnos:
    indices = list(range(9))
    for i in range(9):
        placement= np.random.choice(indices)
        indices.remove(placement)
        player = next(players)
        board[np.unravel_index(placement, (3, 3))] = player

        print(board, "\n")
        if row_win(board, player) or col_win(board, player) or diag_win(board, player):
            print("Gana el jugador {}.".format(player))
            break
    else:
        print("Empate.")
```

**Simulaciones de ejemplo**

```
>>> board = create_board()
>>> juego(board, [1,2])

[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]] 

[[ 0.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]] 

[[ 0.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  2.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]] 

Gana el jugador 2.

>>> board = create_board()
>>> juego(board, [1,2])

[[ 0.  0.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]] 

[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.]] 

[[ 2.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.]] 

[[ 2.  1.  2.]
 [ 2.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.]] 

Empate.


>>> board = create_board()
>>> juego(board, [1,2])

[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.]] 

[[ 2.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]] 

Gana el jugador 1.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla. Abusando de tu bondad, quisiera me ayudaras a corregir este código. Es sobre el mismo tema, pero quiero crear una función que tras ser llamada una vez cree un juego completo de gato. Pondré el código como respuesta porque los comentarios no me permiten hacerlo. ¡Gracias!